# It says "question eligible for bounty since Feb 16" but there is no link to start the bounty

Tags: support, bounties

In

[Do the LIGO observations constitute proof of a black hole merger, and what happened to the black holes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/236107)

it is said:

"question eligible for bounty since Feb 16" but there is no link to start the bounty ...

Could someone explain what is going on there?

P.S. I just deleted my answer and yet there is no link to start the bounty ... So what is happening now?

Answer (score 4):

You posted an answer to that question, so the minimum bounty amount for *you* to set a bounty is 100 rep.

From [What is a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

You only have 91 rep on that site currently, so you don't have enough to afford the minimum bounty. You need 10 more rep, at least, before you can start one on that question.

As for deleting your answer not giving you the link, you have still *posted* an answer, even if you've deleted it. Your answer isn't gone for good- It's soft-deleted, and can easily (especially by you) be un-deleted. If the bounty amount lowered upon deleting your answer, this would be a very easy avenue for abuse: Delete answer, post 50 rep bounty, undelete answer, profit.

Bounties have been around for a long time. I would be surprised if that specific scenario hadn't already been found and handled.

Comment: I just deleted my answer and yet there is no link to start the bounty ... So what is happening now?

Comment: You've still _posted_ an answer to that question, even if it's been deleted. (Keep in mind posts are soft-deleted on the sites- Users with 10k rep on a given site can still see deleted answers.) This is probably to prevent a case of delete the answer, start the bounty, undelete the answer as a way to get around the 100 rep minimum.

Comment: So what would happen if I would first start the bounty and then attempted to answer my own question?

Comment: If you had bountied before ever posting an answer, your minimum bounty would have been 50 rep. The system has yet to learn to tell the future, and the bounty amount can't be changed after the bounty has been posted. There would be no way to tell you were _going_ to answer your question, and therefore the minimum couldn't be increased.